# Why is winload.exe.mui missing

Tags: windows-7, boot

I want to change the boot loader using Win7BootLoaderUpdater, but when I run it it tells me that winload.ex.mui and winresume.exe.mui were not to be found.

I tried to select it but I didn't find it, even tough I performed a search in `system32/`. However, if used the normal explorer, the search showed me a file `C:/windows/system32/boot/winload.exe.mui` but when I open the dialog in Win7BootUpdater and enter directly this path it says not found.

Note: When I boot I first get `Starting windows` then a second after the vista progress loader. It is in English whereas I'm french (and everything else is translated). I have w7 x64  pro.
Finally resolved: I changed using easyBCD the country in the options, and it worked!

**But why such problems?**

Comment: Now that you've resolved this, consider adding your own answer to this and accepting it. If you think someone can give a better answer, then don't do so **yet**.

Comment: A question: what is "Win7BootLoaderUpdater"? I don't remember such an application in Windows for updating the bootloader (it is BCDEdit in Vista and up) and a quick search in Google didn't find any meaningful results.